# How to know if file already exists with Firefox iMacros

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I'm using iMacros firefox addon to automatize redundant tasks like downloading bills (pdf files) from a website to my local disk. 
What I want is, if bill has been already downloaded, to not ask for download next time. Is there a way to know if a file already exists locally ?
My macros are integrated in a js script.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround for that:

```
var ret = iimPlayCode("SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE D:\\iMacros\\Downloads\\blablabla.pdf");
if (ret == 1) {
    // file exists
} else {
    // file doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you Shugar !

Comment: Your else part (file doesn't exit) is not "completely" correct, only the Contrary is True, which will be "good enough" I guess in 95% of the "Cases" for most Users but you'll be missing some "Cases".

ret <> 1 does not mean that 'file doesn't exit'. There are many return codes possible like -910, -930. See documentation for more detail. However in most cases, you just need to handle file exist case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ret = iimPlayCode("SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE D:\\iMacros\\Downloads\\blablabla.pdf");
if (ret == 1) {
    // file exists
} else {
    // file doesn't exist
}
```

This code no work for me.

Comment: Try SET !DATASOURCE instead of SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of SET !DATASOURCE command.

```
var retCode = iimPlayCode("SET !DATASOURCE C:\\my<SP>folder\\my<SP>file.csv");
if (retCode == 1)
{
    alert("WARNING! - File already exists.");
    //action you want to take
}
```

Replace all backslash ('\') with '\' and spaces with < SP > (without spaces) in the file path.

You can use FILEDELETE command to delete exisiting file if you want.

Note: Return code 1 means file exists. Not equal to 1 does not mean that file does not exis, there are many return codes possible like -910. See documentation for more detail. However in most cases, you just need to handle file exist case.